# Mongoose find nested item in array and return if match condition

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find items in nested array and return only if match a specific condition.

Detail:

I have this model:

```js
var Conversation = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true},
  speakers: [{ // speakers array contain all speakers included and whether a speaker can view this conversation or not
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    canView: { // whether to show this conversation to this user
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  }],
};
```

With user ID `"5e09658ccff71014da5d4a0c"`, I want to find all conversations that including him and he can view.

Right now I just can find all conversations including the user with:

```js
Conversation.find({ 'speakers.user': { $all: ["5e09658ccff71014da5d4a0c"] } })
```

But I don't know how to specify the condition (`canView`)

Does anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it  with [`$elementMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Something like this:

```
Conversation.find({
  speakers: {
    $elemMatch: {
      user: ObjectId("5e1cb844b99aae764d59d70a"),
      canView: true
    }
  }
});
```